# Android app lags while making a HTTP url connection

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, httpconnection

I'm trying to send a HTTP request every time someone taps on send button in my firebase chat room app. That request isn't related to Firebase. But important for some functionality in it.

Every time I tap on send button, my app lags a little bit. Also everytime I call the Firebase function first before I send this http request, my app completely freezes...

Calling only Firebase is super smooth...

I also want to send the typing signal via http connection to a different server. But due to this lag it's almost impossible...

This is my code,

```
   public static String post(URL url, String data) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        Thread httpThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", userAgent);
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);

                    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
                            conn.getOutputStream());
                    writer.write(data);
                    writer.flush();


                    String line;

                    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            conn.getInputStream()));
                    try {
                        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                            out.append(line).append("\n");
                        }
                    } finally {
                        input.close();
                    }
                    latch.countDown();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }


            }

        });
        httpThread.start();
        try {
            latch.await();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Sending Output : "+out);
        return out.toString().trim();


    }
```

Also, I tried testing with specific **AsyncTask** class, but I'm getting the same lag or freezing issue. What am I doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 2):

You're using an HTTP thread, but in the end, you're waiting for the thread to be finished inside your main, UI thread which blocks and lags the application.

You can use the android-async-http library, which is there to help send async (non-blocking) requests:

https://loopj.com/android-async-http/

Add this line in your gradle build file:

```
implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
```

Example of usage:

```
import com.loopj.android.http.*;

AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get("https://www.google.com", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        // called before request is started
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
        // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
        // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
    }

    @Override
    public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
        // called when request is retried
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried making a similar request on Asynchttpclient. But I'm constantly getting bad request error. Can you please review this code https://pastebin.com/index/PdXHZBUp

Comment: Could you please show more details of your error, things like screenshots, logs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding `usesCleartextTraffic` to `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
        android:required="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>
</application>
```